# Why is the suggested sample size much larger than what's necessary for significance?

Tags: sample-size, proportion, ab-test

Imagine you're doing an A/B-test in Marketing. You send a control group the standard e-mail, and a test group an e-mail in which one element was changed (for example the color of a button). You want to compare the conversion rates of the e-mails, to determine whether the new e-mail leads to a different conversion rate.

Suppose that the base conversion rate is 16%, and you're interested in a Minimun Detectable Effect of at least 2 percentage-points. Power is set at 80% and the significance level at 5%.

In order to determine the minimum number of recipients per version, I used this calculator:

https://www.evanmiller.org/ab-testing/sample-size.html#!16;80;5;2;0

The suggested sample size per variation is 5,352 recipients per version.

However, if I use the calculator below to determine whether a result is significant, I can find significance at much smaller sample sizes:

https://www.socscistatistics.com/tests/ztest/default2.aspx

For example, if I enter 0.16 and 0.18 (two percentage-points higher) as achieved proportions (conversion rates) and sample sizes of 2,725 for each sample, the result is already significant.

**Question**

Why would the first calculator suggest a much larger sample size than is required for significance, for the same resulting proportions?
(or in more general terms: is it true that the sample size should be much larger than what seems to be minimally required to achieve significance? And if so, why?)

**Own guess**

My guess is that it has something to do with uncertainty and variability: a larger sample size would make it more likely to find a detectable effect in case of some random noise. I also thought it might have to do with that the first calculator considers a double-sided hypothesis (the effect can go either way). But then in the second calculator, I do select the option for two-tailed test. As you can see I'm not sure about it, and of course these explanations are not very formal and well-formulated. Hence any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's your power. Note in that first calculator link you can set the power downward to 60%, and that lowers the sample needed to 3310. If you could lower the power there to 50%, you would likely get 2725.

When you make that significance test using the second calculator, you are at a critical point. If you had one less positive result, you wouldn't be statistically significant. That's essentially coin flip, i.e. a 50-50 chance you'd find a difference.  You want a better chance than that to find a 2% difference if it really exists (specifically, you asked for an 80% chance).